# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException, delete button

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, laravel, datatable

I have a rare issue, I'm using **Laravel 4** with php and I have a *"Delete"* button in a jQuery `datatable` and I'm deleting registries, when I press the button (in any other data than the first) call the `tipos.destoy` method and works fine! But when I press the first *Delete* button, it throws me the exception:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

#### Route:

```
Route::resource('tipos', 'TiposController');
```

#### Controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $this->tipo->find($id)->delete();
        return Redirect::route('tipos.index');
    }
```

#### Model:

```
protected $guarded = array();

protected $table = 'tipos';

protected $fillable = array('clave_tipo', 'nombre_tipo', 'created_by', 'updated_by');

public static $rules = array(
    'clave_tipo' => 'required',
    'nombre_tipo' => 'required',
    'created_by' => 'required',
    'updated_by' => 'required'
);
```

View:

```
@foreach($tipos as $tipo)
    <tr>
        <td>{{{ $tipo->clave_tipo }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ $tipo->nombre_tipo }}}</td>
        <td>{{ link_to_route('tipos.edit', 'EDITAR', array($tipo->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('tipos.destroy', $tipo->id))) }}
            {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I have no idea why it works fine to all the other buttons but only with **the first** button throws the excepetion.
Any help will be really grateful.

Comment: When you specify a route in a Form::open() you've not to set the http method.

Comment: sorry I don't understand, can you be more specific please.

Comment: Just to clarify what you're asking, your specific issue is when you click the `btn-danger` element in the form above Laravel is throwing the `MethodNotAllowed` exception?

Comment: yes, only in the btn btn-danger, I have a datatable, so I have many delete buttons, but only when i press the first (delete) button, throws me that exception, when I press any other delete button (except the first) works fine and the datatable delete the register.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your form, though I will mention that it will probably help you debug this if you 1) inspect the rendered html output of the form to ensure it matches what you would expect, and 2) verify the URL _after_ clicking one of the delete buttons matches what you expect it does. One of those is most likely off somehow

Comment: Actually when I use the developer tool of gchrome, the first data that throws the exception dont have a: 

<form method="POST" action="some/url" accept-charser="UTF-8">

But all the others have it! how can I edit this specific line that the firs parameter don't have it? if i'm using the form::open and form::submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, I just add another form:

```
<td>
    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/posm/public/tipos/" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="zrWDtdGVRnzreYGnZizSHqeIo7jPQlXBlGP03iJW">
    </form>
    {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('tipos.destroy', $tipo->id))) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
</td>
```

I don't clearly know why i have to do this, i think is a bug of laravel or something, but it works, thanks!